# How to get more than 100 different records per day per query using Twitter's standard API?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to download a list of Tweets using the standard API, but what I get are always the same records.
i.e., this is my request:

```
ApiSearch = api.search(q="#immigration", lang="en", result_type="mixed", count=100, until=untilDate, include_entities=False)
```

but if I run it now and then between 1 hour the result I get is the same.

Is there something wrong in the settings of my `api.search` or did I misunderstood the limits of the Twitter standard API?

This is my code:

```
conn_str = ("DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};"
    "DATABASE=TwitterLCL;"
    "UID=postgres;"
    "PWD=pswd;"
    "SERVER=localhost;"
    "PORT=5432;")

consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

col_db_tweetTable01 =  ['CREATED_AT', 'TWEET_ID', 'TEXT', 'USER_ID']

i = 0
while i <= 10000:
    time.sleep(2)
    i += 1
    ApiSearch = api.search(q="#immigration", lang="en", result_type="mixed", count=100, until=None, include_entities=False)
    time.sleep(2)
    for res in range(0, len(ApiSearch)):
        db_tweetTable01DB = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_db_tweetTable01) #creates a new dataframe that's empty
        TWEET = ApiSearch[res]._json
        Created_At = None
        Created_At = TWEET.get("created_at")
        print("Created_At : "+Created_At)
        Tweet_Id = None
        Tweet_Id = TWEET.get("id_str")
        Text = None
        Text = TWEET.get("text")
        User_Id = TWEET.get("user").get("id_str")
        db_tweetTable01DB = db_tweetTable01DB.append({'CREATED_AT' : Created_At, 'TWEET_ID' : Tweet_Id, 'TEXT' : Text, 'USER_ID' : User_Id}, ignore_index=True)
        try:
            connStr = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
            cursor = connStr.cursor()
            for index, row in db_tweetTable01DB.iterrows():
                #print(row)
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO public.db_tweettable01(CREATED_AT, TWEET_ID, TEXT, USER_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)", row['CREATED_AT'], row['TWEET_ID'], row['TEXT'], row['USER_ID'])
                connStr.commit()
            cursor.close()
            connStr.close()
        except pyodbc.Error as ex:
            sqlstate = ex.args[1]
            print(sqlstate)
            print("Tweet_Id : "+Tweet_Id)
            print("User_Id : "+User_Id)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

As I answered in [your Tweepy issue on GitHub](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1325), a "mixed" `result_type` includes both popular and recent results. You'll want to specify "recent" if you only want the most recent results. As I also explained, you'll want to use the `since_id` parameter to avoid getting duplicate Tweets.

See [the documentation for `API.search`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#API.search) and [the standard search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets).

If you're going to be iterating over the paginated results over a short time frame like 2 seconds, rather than an hour, you can use a [Cursor](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor_tutorial.html) instead.

As for more than 100 results per query, the limit of the standard search API is a maximum of 100 per page, so that's not possible.

Comment: Harmon thanks for your help. instead of using since_id I used max_id and that solved.

Comment: You should [accept the answer, rather than comment to say thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).